# ActiveMQ install issue

Tags: installation, activemq-classic

I am running win7 professional 64-bit.  I have already installed java, and am trying to install ActiveMQ.  The install worked perfectly on a Windows Server 2003 machine but now it is giving me issues on my win7 machine.  I download ActiveMQ 5.3.2 extract the files and then try to run the installservice.bat file as administrator and it gives me the following error in command prompt: **'"wrapper.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Comment: Do you have wrapper.exe in your <ACTIVE_MQ_HOME>\bin\win32?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when using Windows Explorer and right clicking on the InstallService.bat file and selecting "Run As Administrator".

However, this worked for me (without having to change my user control settings):
1) Open a command prompt (right clicking first with "run as administrator").
2) Then navigate to the folder where your batch file is and simply type InstallService.bat.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel a little stupid answering my own question but here it goes. Turn off the user control settings in the control panel

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with apache-activemq-5.6.0 and solved it this way:

1. Open `cmd.exe` as admin (click on Start, type in `cmd`, right click on the "cmd" program, and choose `Run as administrator`)
2. In the `cmd.exe` window, navigate to your apache-activemq-5.X.X root dir (which contains `bin`, `conf`, `data`, `docs`, ...)
3. From there, navigate to `bin\win64`
4. Your commmand prompt should show something like:

   ```
   ...\apache-activemq-5.6.0\bin\win64>
   ```
5. Still in the `cmd.exe`, run `InstellService.bat`

It does not work if you run something like `win64\InstellService.bat` while being in `bin`. You have to actually navigate to `bin\win64` first.

Answer (score 0):

The in case you are installing in win 64 bit 2012 Server too, run InstallService.bat under sys32. 
Its little confusing but it works.